# DOMPDF not rendering in codeigniter php

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

There are situations where you find this error when rendering PDF documents using DOMPDF library in Codeigniter. It becomes confusing when it works on localhost but breaks when moved to an online server.

This code works fine when the **Attachment** is set to true but fails when false.

$dompdf->loadHtml($html_content);

$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->stream($document_title, ["compress" => 1, "Attachment" => true]);

%PDF-1.7 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [6 0 R ] /Count 1 /Resources << /ProcSet 4 0 R /Font << /F1 8 0 R /F2 9 0 R >> /XObject << /I1 13 0 R /I2 14 0 R /I3 17 0 R >> /ExtGState << /GS1 10 0 R /GS2 11 0 R /GS3 15 0 R /GS4 16 0 R >> >> /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890] >> endobj 4 0 obj [/PDF /Text /ImageC ]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding **exit();** at the bottom of the code.

$dompdf->loadHtml($html_content);

$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->stream($document_title, ["compress" => 1, "Attachment" => false]);

exit();